# Как правильно применять интонационный анализ?

Tags: пунктуация, интонация

Интонационный анализ помогает при решении задач **с вариантами,** когда в правилах говорится о **факультативности** постановки знаков.

Но как **правильно** его применять?

Answer (score 2):

Я попробую **обобщить** свой опыт по этой теме.

Действительно, интонационный анализ представляется **очень важным**, когда в правилах предлагается **выбор решения**:  обособлять или не обособлять, использовать двоеточие или тире и т.д.

Но как **правильно** его применить? Мне представляется, что при отсутствии такого понимания интонационный анализ может **не помочь**, а напротив, привести к **неправильному** решению.

Здесь важно помнить о **трех принципах** русской пунктуации и при постановке знаков учитывать все: **семантику, грамматику, интонацию.**

**Шаг 1. Интонация как версия**

Нужно услышать предложение, понять смысл и предположить форму записи. В этом помогает **чувство языка и опыт** общения с текстами. Некоторые пользователи правильно ставят знаки на этом этапе.

**Шаг 2.  Семантика (содержание)**

Надо хорошо понять смысл сказанного, можно  заменить пересказом содержания своими словами.

**Шаг 3. Грамматика и структура предложения**

Грамматический принцип в правилах письма считается **ведущим**, и это действительно так. Как ставить знаки, если не понимать грамматику предложения.
Также **структура** предложения (распространенность, порядок слов и т.д.) должна обязательно учитываться.

**Шаг 4. Правила пунктуации**

Нужно найти **подходящее правило** по теме и ссылку на него.

**Шаг 5. Интонация как проверка**

Начальная версия проверяется **по всем показателям**, и тогда принимается окончательное **решение**. Можно использовать интонационную **схему**, обозначив паузы и ударения.

**Вывод.**  При правильном интонационном анализе  решение **начинается** с интонации и **заканчивается** ею.

Comment: Интонационный принцип пунктуации или, как вы говорите, интонационный анализ, следует применять в совокупности с другими принципами пунктуации.